# Run shell script before setup in setup.py

Tags: python, numpy, setup.py

I want to run a bash shell script before running `setup` is called in a setup.py:

```py
from numpy.distutils.core import setup, Extension
from subprocess import call

err = call('sh dependencies.sh',shell=True)
if err:
    raise Exception('The dependencies failed to compile.')

extensions = [...]

setup(name = 'Package',
      packages=['Package'],
      ext_modules=extensions)
```

When I run `python -m pip install . -v`, everything works. HOWEVER, the script `dependencies.sh` is run two times, compiling the dependencies two times. How do I do this properly? Thanks!

Comment: BTW, `call('sh dependencies.sh', shell=True)` starts _two_ shells for no good reason (`shell=True` starts the first, and the copy of `sh` it starts is the second). `call(['sh', 'dependencies.sh'])` is one way to start only one, `call('. dependencies.sh', shell=True)` another; `sh(['./dependencies.sh'])` is an even better one (assuming your file has a `#!/bin/sh` shebang or similar and `+x permissions).

Comment: That said, if your program is packaged as a Python egg, `dependencies.sh` won't be invoked _at all_, by design (arbitrary code execution at install time is often used for malfeasance).

Comment: Thanks! its not arbitary code execution though. I'm compiling a fortran extension with f2py. But the fortran extension depends on a C library. So I need to compile the C library then compile the fortran with f2py linking the compiled C library.

Comment: That still doesn't make dropping to shell at install time rather than build time something that'll make a paranoid sysadmin happy.

Comment: See https://numpy.org/devdocs/f2py/distutils.html for the Right Way to do setuptools compilation with f2py.

Comment: Trying to drive this from Python is putting the cart before the horse.

Comment: Iv been through the f2py distutils documentation. It isn’t very clear how to compile dependencies, before using f2py to compile the main package.